# Flow union types and optional properties

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I just ran into an issue that is baffling me with `flow`. Can someone please explain to me why the following does not work, and how I would go about fixing it?

```
// @flow

type MessageDescriptor = {
  id: string,
  defaultMessage?: string,
  description?: string
};

type MenuLabel = MessageDescriptor & {
  +values?: { +[name: string]: string }
};

const msg: MessageDescriptor = {
  id: 'test'
};

const label: MenuLabel = msg;
```

The error I get is:

```
9: type MenuLabel = MessageDescriptor & {                                        
                                        ^ property `values`. Property not found in

17: const label: MenuLabel = msg;
                             ^ object type
```

However, `values` is obviously optional. Even more bizarrely, the following works:

```
const label: MenuLabel = { ...msg };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that to make "Intersection Types + Optionals" work you have to define the optional value in both types.

```
// @flow

type MessageDescriptor = {
  id: string,
  defaultMessage?: string,
  description?: string,
  +values?: { +[name: string]: string }
};


type MenuLabel = MessageDescriptor & {
  +values?: { +[name: string]: string }
};

const msg: MessageDescriptor = {
  id: 'test'
};

const label: MenuLabel = msg;
```

Given the comments, maybe you are looking for a Union Type instead of an Intersection Type?

```
// @flow

type MessageDescriptor = {
  id: string,
  defaultMessage?: string,
  description?: string,
};


type MenuLabel = MessageDescriptor | {
  +values?: { +[name: string]: string }
};

const msg: MessageDescriptor = {
  id: 'test'
};

const label: MenuLabel = msg;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a real solution, because they originate from different libraries, so I can't change the `MessageDescriptor` type.

Comment: I see, isn't a Union type what you want instead of an intersection type?

Comment: No. I need the following to be valid `MenuLabel` value: `{ id: 'test', values: { foo: 'bar' } }`